# Should I be running fstrim in a container?

Tags: docker

If I run `fstrim` in a docker container I get errors about host-mounted(?) files being **`not a directory`**.

```
$ docker run -ti -v tmp:/tmp2 ubuntu:16.04 /sbin/fstrim --all
fstrim: /etc/hosts: not a directory
fstrim: /etc/hostname: not a directory
fstrim: /etc/resolv.conf: not a directory
fstrim: /tmp2: FITRIM ioctl failed: Operation not permitted
```

I'm guessing this is because the container isn't [privileged](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run.md#runtime-privilege-and-linux-capabilities). (at least the `FITRIM ioctl failed` error)

*I discovered this by installing `cron` on a fresh `ubuntu:16.04` container (I know it violates the "one process" philosophy - that's another discussion)* But the default image has `/etc/cron.weekly/fstrim` so once you install cron, `fstrim` starts running weekly and cron emails me the errors.

**Should I be running `fstrim` in a container?**

*I'm still wrapping my head around `aufs` and all the pages I found about `fstrim` talk about SSDs and free space recovery.*
**Does any of this apply in a container?**  Won't the host's fstrim cron job take care of everything?  Should I remove the cron job from the container or is a bug in docker?

edit: system info:

```
$ uname -sri; docker --version
Linux 4.4.0-53-generic x86_64
Docker version 1.12.3, build 6b644ec
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fstrim` makes absolutely no sense inside a container.

The point of `fstrim` is to unmap unused storage on the backing store, whether that's a local SSD or thin provisioned SAN storage mounted via iSCSI, FibreChannel, or whatever. Such a process needs to run on the host, rather than inside a container.

The specific errors you see are because `fstrim` attempts to call the FITRIM ioctl on each mount point, and mount points inside a container do not correspond to the actual block devices the host is using. This is generally true even if the container is privileged.

Why Ubuntu puts `fstrim` in a container image is a complete mystery. If you're stuck with Ubuntu containers, I would suggest disabling that cron job.

Comment: thanks for in the info.  I started an issue at https://github.com/tianon/docker-brew-ubuntu-core/issues/72 to not include `/etc/cron.weekly/fstrim` in the image.